# Keyboard hotkey for "Flush all caches"?

Tags: caching

Is there any easy way to create a **keyboard hotkey** to flush all caches in a Drupal site?, instead of going to [Admin menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_menu) Drupal icon and click that time and again? Thx.

Comment: Look at Drush, or set up your Cron Jobs. You shouldn't need to manually clear the cache so often that it needs a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Or even better, turn off caching altogether when you're developing. Then turn it back on when you're done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've enabled the search bar component on Admin menu you can search your way to it.

[image: Admin menu's search components]

1. Enable the Search Bar component on the configuration page (**/admin/config/administration/admin_menu**).
2. Type "flu.." or enough characters to list only the "Flush all caches" menu item.
3. Press the tab key to highlight and the enter key to trigger the "Flush all caches" menu item.

[image: Searching through admin menu's items]

Comment: One could argue that this is no faster than using the flush caches link admin menu already provides.

Answer (score 2):

[Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module also has such feature , you can access that link by enabling module and placing development block somewhere in your access .

Devel has many other facilities for working with drupal .

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to create such hotkey with Devel?

Comment: Just Download and Install [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module , after enabling that go to Structure -> Blocks and you will find a development Block , this Block contains some facilities like "Clear all caches" menu and ability to run PHP Code Directly in a page .